# How to get the current View Name in Vaadin

Tags: java, view, vaadin, navigator

I'm using Vaadin 7. I want to redirect my page to a previous one after a treatment is done. For that I need to know which View called my new View so I can redirect to it later. I'm aware that I have to add something in here:

```
 getNavigator().addViewChangeListener(new ViewChangeListener() {

  @Override
  public boolean beforeViewChange(ViewChangeEvent event) {

    myNewView.REDIRECT_TO = //here is the problem :)
}
```

Any Idea how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ViewChangeEvent.getOldView()` method to retrieve the `View` object. Now, by default there's no way to get the name of the view from there, since in theory you could register the same `View` with multiple names. But assuming you have only one name for each view, here's what you could do:

Create an interface, `HasName`, like so:

```
public interface HasName {
    String getName();
}
```

Then implement `HasName` in all your `View` classes. When registering the views in your `Navigator`, use the `getName()` method to refer to the name of the `View`. After that you can simply do a cast in your `ViewChangeListener` and use the same method to access the name there.

```
getNavigator().addViewChangeListener(new ViewChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean beforeViewChange(ViewChangeEvent event) {
        View oldView = event.getOldView();
        if (oldView != null) {
            String oldViewName = ((HasName) oldView).getName();
            // do stuff with oldViewName
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I got a `NullPointerException` when I try to get the name !

Comment: Oh right, I guess `getOldView()` will return `null` if you're just opening the app for the first time. I added a `null` check to my example code.

Comment: What is the package of HasName class?